# Error with Array getting Empty Set

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

**Updated Problem:** `print_r($_POST);` in the php file outputs after I type something in the box.

```
Array
(
    [q] => running
)
```

print `json_encode($jsonArray);` however is printing `[]`

The php which queries Interest table for the bound parameter

```
    $interestValue = $_POST['interestVal']; //////
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
    $sth = $dbh->prepare(
'SELECT interestID, interestVal FROM Interest WHERE interestVal = ?');
    $sth->bindParam(1, $interestValue);
    $sth->execute();
    $jsonArray = array();
    while ($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $jsonArray[] = array(
      'ID' => $result['interestID'], 
          'Value' => $result['interestVal']); 
    }

    print_r($_POST);

    print json_encode($jsonArray); // json encode that array
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="interest" name="interest" value="What are your interests?" />
```

**JS**

```
//Get interests
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input#interest").tokenInput("../../src/php/registration/interest/getInterest.php");
        });
```

The JS of the framework(http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

```
(function ($) {
// Default settings
var DEFAULT_SETTINGS = {
    // Search settings
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "json",
    queryParam: "interestVal",
    searchDelay: 300,
    minChars: 1,
    propertyToSearch: "name",
    jsonContainer: null,

    // Display settings
    hintText: "Type in a search term",
    noResultsText: "No results",
    searchingText: "Searching...",
    deleteText: "&times;",
    animateDropdown: true,

    // Tokenization settings
    tokenLimit: null,
    tokenDelimiter: ",",
    preventDuplicates: false,

    // Output settings
    tokenValue: "name", // orig "id"
}
```

**Why is this array empty??**

Comment: Yes. Which means it isn't getting anything from the query?

Comment: Is something in PDO malformed?

Comment: whats does this show: print $interestValue;

Comment: I tried that too. The thing is though, when I type "running" into the input it calls the JS above and calls the php file. I dont see how it would output this value

Comment: I'm trying to set this up: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ . I wonder if this is the reason "Your script must accept a GET parameter named q which will contain the term to search for" ??

Comment: Found the problem: there is no $_GET variable being appended to the URL if i manually type getInterest.php?q=Running for example it finds it fine. How do I get this variable in the URL upon entering something?

Comment: @jarchuleta please see updated code. I atleast have the value inputted into an array, it appears to not be able to put this in json format with the actual values for the query term though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` with prepared statements - binding parameters takes the user data out of the SQL code, so there are no SQL injection vulnerabilities. More importantly, `mysql_real_escape_string` only works AFTER you connect to the DB, not before, which is turning your value into `false`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I remove mysql_real_escape_string. Now it just says "searching..." forever. I tried manually looking at the php script. Its still outputting 
json array var Array[] when I try to echo 'json array var '.$jsonArray; right after while{}

Comment: Then you should either set up xdebug, or start echoing values in your PHP. Also make sure to check your error logs.

Comment: You can't echo an array. Try print_r($jsonArray);

Comment: Yeah. you can see the outputting I tried above. It printed out empty values for both variables. I also checked the catch{} block for this file and its blank

Comment: Good catch @Ryan - it still is a blank array() though

Comment: array() is no longer blank, its getting the inputted value, but its having difficulty putting this in json format with the values it grabs from the database. Any thoughts here?

Comment: What difficulty? Any error messages? And print_r would be good.